# Serialize ZonedDateTime in Kotlin data class

Tags: datetime, kotlin, jackson

I get the following error when I serialize a `ZonedDateTime` field in a data class:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is KClass<ZonedDateTimeSerializer> but KClass<out KSerializer<*>> was expected
```

Here is my class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.ZonedDateTimeSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import java.time.ZonedDateTime

@Serializable
data class MyClass(
    @Serializable(ZonedDateTimeSerializer::class)
    val time: ZonedDateTime
)
```

How can I serialize a `ZonedDateTime` in Kotlin?

Comment: Does `ZonedDateTimeSerializer` implement `KSerializer`?

Comment: No. That's a Jackson class.

Comment: Well, then of course it doesn't work.

Comment: also see recently released org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.2.0 which supports kotlinx.serialization
https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/05/kotlinx-datetime-0-2-0-is-out/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
object KZonedDateTimeSerializer : KSerializer<ZonedDateTime> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("ZonedDateTime", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: ZonedDateTime) {
        encoder.encodeString(value.toString())
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): ZonedDateTime {
        val string = decoder.decodeString()
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(string)
    }
}
```

Here's for OffsetDateTime. If you don't specify a formatter, the minute is removed if it is zero:

```
object KOffsetDateTimeSerializer : KSerializer<OffsetDateTime> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("OffsetDateTime", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: OffsetDateTime) {
        val format = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME

        val string = format.format(value)
        encoder.encodeString(string)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): OffsetDateTime {
        val string = decoder.decodeString()
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(string)
    }
}
```